# --dart-define and Firebase in a Flutter App

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, environment-variables

I want to use *--dart-define* in my Firebase Flutter App to specify different build environments (Deveopment/Test/Production). It is working well for changing the Application-ID, but I also need to use a different *google-services.json* file for each environment.

Is there any way to specify the *google-services.json* file using --dart-define?

Build flavors are not an option for me.